# conditional attribute using knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, attributes

I want to conditionally add a ID attribute to the **div** tag

I tried something like this

```
 <div class="row" data-bind="attr: { id:'selectedReplyMessage': $component.selectedReplyMessageID() == _id }"></div>
```

But it didnt work

Although this code

```
<div class="row" data-bind=" css:{selectedReplyMessage: $component.selectedReplyMessageID() == _id }">
```

is working completely fine.But i want to associate ID with the component.

Comment: @adiga I didnt find answer over there

Comment: Did you try any of them?

Comment: Yes i mentioned the one i tried

Comment: As mentioned in one of the answers, use ternary operator and set the id to `null` when you don;t want it to be shown. It should be `<div class="row" data-bind="attr: { id: $component.selectedReplyMessageID() == _id ? 'selectedReplyMessage' : null }"></div>` This will set the `id="selectedReplyMessage"` when the condition is `true` and the attribute won;t be added at all when the condition is `false`

Comment: Yea it worked ,thanks .Should i post the answer or delete the post . It might help the upcoming people who are new to knockout and confused

Comment: You can post it as an answer and accept it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Adigo

```
 <div class="row" data-bind="attr: { id: $component.selectedReplyMessageID() == _id ? 'selectedReplyMessage' : null }"></div>
```

Doing like this way you can acheive you desired output.Using ternary operator and putting the values.